# How to know if an async method is running

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a button that on click event goes and get data from server and displays that on a grid.

The code is like below:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here I should do something in order to know if the async ProcessSearch method is busy..
    // if not busy then I will execute it if not then I will return.
    // shows loading animation
    ShowPleaseWait(Translate("Searching data. Please wait..."));
    ProcessSearch();
}

private async void ProcessSearch()
{
    Data.SeekWCF seekWcf = new Data.SeekWCF();
    _ds = await seekWcf.SearchInvoiceAdminAsync(new Guid(cboEmployer.Value.ToString()), new Guid(cboGroup.Value.ToString()), txtSearchInvoiceNumber.Text, chkSearchLike.Checked, txtSearchFolio.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Value));
    seekWcf.Dispose();

    if (_ds != null)
    {
        SetupInvoiceGrid();
    }
    // hides the loading animation
    HidePleaseWait();
}
```

How can I know if the async method ProcessSearch is busy or running so I can prevent the user to execute the method again when clicking the button again.

Comment: BTW, you should use `async void` only at the top level. That is, `ProcessSearch()` should be an `async Task` method and `btnSearch_Click` should be an `async void` method that `await`s the result of `ProcessSearch()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just set a boolean:

```
private bool isSearching = false;

private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isSearching)
        return;
    // shows loading animation
    ShowPleaseWait(Translate("Searching data. Please wait..."));
    ProcessSearch();
}

private async void ProcessSearch()
{
    isSearching = true;

    // do other stuff

    isSearching = false;
}
```

If you're concerned about concurrency, you could add a [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx):

```
private bool isSearching = false;
private object lockObj = new object();

private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (lockObj)
    {
        if (isSearching)
            return;
        else
            isSearching = true;
    }
    // shows loading animation
    ShowPleaseWait(Translate("Searching data. Please wait..."));
    ProcessSearch();
}

private async void ProcessSearch()
{
    // do other stuff

    isSearching = false;
}
```

Comment: there is no built in "IsBusy" property in async operator or something? Like the BackgroundWorkers?

Comment: technically this code is prone to a race condition. While unlikely to occur, you should use a lock to protect yourself.

Comment: @VAAA There's `Task.IsCompleted`, but to use that you'd have to make it `private async Task ProcessSearch()` and store that task in a field; IMO it's simpler easier to just store a boolean.

Comment: @BrokenGlass as long as `btnSearch_Click` is only called from the UI thread, I don't think there is a potential race condition here. I could be wrong.

Comment: @BrokenGlass how would I use the lock? Thats something new for me. Appreciate it

Comment: @VAAA I've added a `lock` example.